# How to remove a text from a txt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, apt

This is my txt file.

```
apache2                     install
apache2-bin                 install
apache2-data                    install
apache2-utils                   install
libapache2-mod-php5.6               install
libapache2-mod-php5.6               install
php-common                  install
php5.6                      install
php5.6-cli                  install
php5.6-common                   install
php5.6-json                 install
php5.6-opcache                  install
php5.6-readline                 install
libmysqlclient20:i386               install
libmysqlcppconn7v5              install
mysql-client                    install
mysql-client-5.7                install
mysql-client-core-5.7               install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-server                    install
mysql-server-5.7                install
mysql-server-core-5.7               install
mysql-utilities                 install
mysql-workbench                 install
mysql-workbench-data                install
python-mysql.connector              install
```

I want remove these words called `install` and the spaces between the module, after I want transform the result to a code inline to me use, like some these:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove apache2 apache2-bin apache-data....
```

I can make this in a text editor, but I can need to know how to make this to future whitout use a text editor.

**Resuming:**
From my txt file, I want something like this:

```
apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php5.0 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question on how to remove lines of text from a textfile:

```
grep -v pattern lists.txt > new_lists.txt
```

Comment: See the edition, do you can help me?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your question doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You must use two tools: [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and [tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)

```
sed -e 's/\s*install\s*$//g' txt|tr '\n' ' '
```

`sed` removes everything except packages names. `tr` replaces new lines with space.

```
sudo apt-get remove `sed -e 's/\s*install\s*$//g' txt|tr '\n' ' '`
```

Another solution: [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) and [tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)

```
awk -e '{print $1}' < txt|tr '\n' ' '
```

`awk` prints first column from input data.